# Adjusting speed & position of jQuery animated bubbles

Tags: jquery

I posted another question about another script I wanted to use instead of this one, but no one was able to help, so I decided to try and get this one working how I'd like. I have read a few other questions pertaining to this topic, but I cannot figure out how to apply those solutions to the script I am using.

I would like to keep the bubbles from speeding up and getting clumped together at the top of the screen after a few seconds. I have been able to slow down the initial speed of the bubbles by adjusting rand and horiSpeed, but it did not fix the subsequent speeding up or clumping.

I also played around with setInterval, but no luck there either. If anyone can point me in the right direction and also explain what the different functions are doing, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am particularly confused by the 15 and 250 in the parts below:

```
 marginLeft: function (n, v) {
                return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 15000) + rand) + 1) * parentW;
            }
        });
    }, 15);

    setInterval(function () {
        if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
            current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
        }
    }, 250);
```

The script follows and here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N63Tf/5/

```
       jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function (vertSpeed, horiSpeed, index) {

    this.css('float', 'left');

    vertSpeed = vertSpeed || 1;
    horiSpeed = 1 / horiSpeed || 1;

    var windowH = this.parent().height(),
        thisH = this.height(),
        parentW = (this.parent().width() - this.width()) / 2,
        rand = Math.random() * (index * 10000),            
        current = this;

    this.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
    this.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    setInterval(function () {
        current.css({
            marginTop: function (n, v) {
                return parseFloat(v) - vertSpeed;
            },
            marginLeft: function (n, v) {
                return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 15000) + rand) + 1) * parentW;
            }
        });
    }, 15);

    setInterval(function () {
        if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
            current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
        }
    }, 250);


};
var message = 1;
$('.message').each(function (message) {
    $(this).verticalMarquee(1, 1, message);
    message++;
});
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT: Questions about functions in Anton's answer.** 
(Too long for a comment and wasn't sure where else to put it.)

When you mention doing all the animating in one loop, do you mean this script could be improved to do so, or that if I want to add more transitions I should keep them within the function in this script?

If the latter is true, where in the code would the new transition go?  Would I create another function and put it after animationStep?

Is the counter part of the function and each transition would have its own?  (It seems to me there would only be one counter, otherwise each transition would generate separate bubbles?)

In the counter, am I correct that this part is checking the bounds of #parent so the bubbles stay within the div, and doing so after every 10th bubble?

```
  if(check && item.y < -item.elementHeight){ //check bounds every 10th iteration
```

Lastly, what does this do? Is it calling the whole function and setting the interval time?  Is this where I can speed up the rate at which the bubbles are generated?

```
 window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
     return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        function( callback ){
         window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
   })();
```

Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random behaviour comes from using floating divs. The browser tries to lay them out and fails, because you are constantly changing the margin.

The first loop with 15ms interval moves the item and the second one checks if it reached the top of the page.

I added some delay to each item (a little timeout) based on its index to prevent them from clumping up.

Some general tips for animating:

1. Try to do all the animating in one loop (so you don't have multiple intervals running)
2. Take a look at the requestAnimationFrame function for smooth animation with 60fps
3. For more performance you can also animate css translate instead of margins.

I added a little delay to prevent the items from cluttering up.
Here is your working piece:

```
    jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function (vertSpeed, horiSpeed, index) {

    this.css('position', 'absolute');

    vertSpeed = vertSpeed || 1;
    horiSpeed = 1 / horiSpeed || 1;

    var windowH = this.parent().height(),
        thisH = this.height(),
        delay= (Math.random()/2+0.5)*3000*index,
        parentW = (this.parent().width() - this.width()) / 2,
        rand = Math.random() * (index * 10000),
        current = this;

    this.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
    this.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    setTimeout(function(){

        setInterval(function () {
            current.css({
                marginTop: function (n, v) {
                    return parseFloat(v) - vertSpeed;
                },
                marginLeft: function (n, v) {
                    return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 15000) + rand) + 1) * parentW;
                }
            });
        }, 15);

        setInterval(function () {
            if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
                current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
            }
        }, 250);
    }, delay);

    };

    $('.message').each(function (index) {
        $(this).verticalMarquee(1, 1, index);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QqMu4/

and that's how it looks with all the things I've said applied:

http://jsfiddle.net/Arimano/549Pa/

Comment: Hi Anton, this is awesome - thanks so much!  I adjusted the horizontal and vertical speeds and now it works just as I wanted. :)
I have a few questions, just so I can keep 

learning. Please know it's fine if you don't have time to delve into all this - I realize it may be way out of scope for a posted question.  Also, I am NOT looking for you to write any more code - this is really just for my own edification. I will add another comment since it's too long to include here.