# Explanation of jQuery animated bubbles script variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

iSchluff provided an awesome solution to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644240/adjusting-speed-position-of-jquery-animated-bubbles) about adjusting the speed and position of jQuery bubbles.

Now I just need help understanding what each variable in the script is doing. The bubbles will contain quotes, so I'm trying to slow them down enough to give people time to read them. I've managed to slow them down significantly by adjusting the `vertSpeed` and `horiSpeed`. However, I've tried adjusting `window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)` and `omega: 2*Math.PI* horiSpeed/(width*60), //omega= 2Pi*frequency` `random: (Math.random()/2+0.5) * i * 10000, //random time offset`, but cannot figure out how to increase the time between each bubble being generated.

Is the section below where I can slow down the rate at which the bubbles are generated? Is it calling the whole function and setting the interval time? If so, shouldn't decreasing the denominator in `setTimeout` slow down the bubble generation?

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
 return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
    function( callback ){
     window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
  };})();
```

In the counter, am I correct that this part is checking the bounds of #parent so the bubbles stay within the div, and doing so after every 10th bubble?

`if(check && item.y < -item.elementHeight){ //check bounds every 10th iteration`

If anyone could shed some light on this for me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

http://jsfiddle.net/N63Tf/19/

Comment: No, that function just returns window.requestAnimationFrame if it exists, otherwise it returns a function that when called executes the callback after ~16ms. there's nothing you can do in that section that will affect the bubble generation rate (bgr)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Kevin. Which variables can I then modify to affect the bubble generation rate?